# Tracking if backspace or delete key is pressed in an input field

Tags: javascript, key, keydown, backspace

I was wondering how i can track if users hit the backspace or delete key in a input field. Afterwhich i would add to a variable called count each time those buttons are pressed. I currently have this code but it does not seem to work; any help is great appreciated, thank you.

```
var Count = 0;

var input = document.getElementById('display');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
        Count++;
        return false;
};
```

Comment: You're always returning `false`. Wrap the conditional in `{}`:  http://jsfiddle.net/a15tfq9o/

Comment: In fact always wrap conditionals so you don't end up with issues like this .

Comment: are you trying to prevent input if those keys are used? Not clear what your objective is

Comment: I'm actually trying to log the number of times those keys are pressed, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

multiple lines inside a conditional or loop, etc. need to be wrapped in braces:

```
if( key == 8 || key == 46 )
{
    Count++;
    return false;
}
```

You will also want to add a default `return true` as the last line to differentiate whether you entered the if or not as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this approach:

```
var count = 0;

var input = document.getElementById('display');

input.onkeydown = function() {
    var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;

    if( key !== 8 && key !== 46 )
        return true;

    count++;
};
```

1. Don't start your variable names with a capital letters unless they are object prototypes you're going to instantiate, ie. `var count = new Count( )`, where you previously defined the `Count` object prototype
2. Always use  a strict comparator, like `===` and `!==`, don't just use `==` and `!=`
3. Check for negative first, and return true if your condition doesn't match. Then execute your code, in your case `count++`